# Custom tab icon based on site url

Tags: css, firefox

In Firefox, I wish to change the tab icon based on the url of the site -- is this possible?

The closest I've gotten is the following (in userChrome.css):

`tab[label*="title of site"] .tab-icon-image { ..custom favicon... }`

Which works!  But as soon as you browse the rest of the site, as the page titles change, it no longer changes the icon, obviously.

I do not wish to use an extension, I'd like to achieve this in css or some sort of profile tweak, if at all possible.

Comment: You'd need javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Good news,

I was able to figure this out without the use of javascript:

`tab[image*='sitename'] .tab-icon-image { ..custom icon.. }`

Hope this helps anyone looking for this type of functionality :)